# is the following properties true for the induced quotient topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let  X be a topological space, M = $X/\sim$ be a equivalence relation on the set X. $f : X \rightarrow M$ be regular map that is $f(t) = [t]$ where $t \in X$ is the following properties true ?

1)If X is $T_0$, then the quotient topology on M will be $T_0$.

2)If X is $T_1$, then the quotient topology on M will be $T_1$.

3)If X is $T_2$, then the quotient topology on M will be $T_2$.

If any of this is true what property is actually preserved in the quotient topology of M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note that $\Bbb{R}$ is $T_2$ ($\Rightarrow \ T_1 \ \Rightarrow \ T_0$). Now, consider $M=\Bbb{R}/\sim$ where $x \sim y$ if $x,y \in \Bbb{Q}$. Look at the point $[0]\in M$.

Comment: so it is actually $T_1,T_2,and T_0$?

Comment: can you add more information about the [0] and about the quotient topology induced by this relation ?

Comment: $M$ is not $T_1$ ($\Rightarrow$ not $T_2$) because $[0]\in M$ is not closed. However, $M$ might actually be $T_0$ (not sure about that), but if you take instead the coarser equivalence relation $x\sim y$ if $x-y \in \Bbb{Q}$, $\Bbb{R}/\sim$ isn't $T_0$. But this equivalence relation is harder to visualize.

Comment: can you explain more why is $[0] \in M$ not closed?

Comment: $\{[0]\}$ is closed in $M$ if and only if $\{x \in \Bbb{R}\mid x\sim 0\}$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}$. What is $\{x \in \Bbb{R}\mid x\sim 0\}$ ?

Comment: $\{x \in R | x \sim 0\} = \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: No, $\{x \in \Bbb{R}\mid x\sim 0\}=\{x \in \Bbb{R}\mid x,0 \in \Bbb{Q}\}=$?

Comment: so it will be all of Q

Comment: Yes, exactly. And $\Bbb{Q}$ isn't closed in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Just one thing I need to understand, but here Q isn't closed in $\mathbb{R}$, but why does it guarantee its not closed in the quotient topology on M?

Comment: also one more thing I don't understand the relation above why is it an equivalence relation why does it partition R we have x ~ y iff $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$ but what about $x \in \mathbb{R}$ not in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: The answer to your first question is: by definition of quotient topology. For the second question, if $x \in \Bbb{R}\backslash \Bbb{Q}$, then $x\sim y$ if and only if $x=y$.

Comment: alright I get it now...